# CSS: Fitting div height into another inclusive padding

Tags: css, html

[image: Final result]

As seen in the picture, I practically have a div of defined width 100% but no defined height, but rather the height is defined to match the contents with a percentage of top and bottom padding.
The problem is I want to have some kind of navigation buttons on the right side, and they must be aligned perfectly in the vertical middle.
I have included a Fiddle of what I did, but it doesn't show in the middle in all cases.
What can be an optimal solution.

**HTML**

```
<div class="title">Title
    <ul id="bullets">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.title {
    width:100%;
    background:#365F95;
    background-size: contain;
    font-size:130%;
    color:#FFF;
    padding:5% 0;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
.title ul {
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0%;
}
.title ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #FFF;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px black, 0 0 1px 1px #202020;
    margin: 0 2px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HJLEe/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HJLEe/5/) The idea is vertically align list

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: - half-height;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution, but it works.

HTML:

```
<div class="title">Title
    <ul id="bullets">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.title {
    width:100%;
    background:#365F95;
    background-size; cover;
    font-size:130%;
    color:#FFF;
    padding:5% 0;
    text-align:center;

}
.title ul {
position:relative;
float: right;
margin-top: 0px;
}
.title ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
height: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #FFF;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px black, 0 0 1px 1px #202020;
    margin: 0 2px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HJLEe/7/)

Answer (score 0):

try use position relative in your ul class

```
 .title ul {
 position: relative;
              }
```

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/HJLEe/10/)

Answer (score 0):

try this `css`

```
.title ul {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0%;
padding-top: inherit;
margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a margin in percentage. Like this...

```
.title ul {
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0%;
    vertical-align :middle;
    margin-top : 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using vertical-align:middle and the helper pseudo element to hold the height.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HJLEe/13/

Essential additions to the code:

```
.title ul {
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

/* style of LIs not changed */

.title ul:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%; /* makes the effective line height equal to the height of the container */
    vertical-align: middle; /* align the vertical center with the vertical middle of the text, including our bullets */
}
```